# Can i get list items' values from another list inside my SharePoint list workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, development, workflow2013

I am working on a classic sharepoint online team site collection. and i have added 2 lists:-

1. Project Management list.
2. Lookup list.

Then using SharePoint Designer i added a SharePoint list workflow 2013 to the Project Management list. But inside this workflow, i want to retrieve the Lookup list's items at each of the workflow's if statments.

Here is my current settings:-

1) The lookup list have values such as :-
[image]

where for each status i define a value (which represents the number of days to complete).

2) Then inside my list workflow on the Project Management list, I have defined If-Statements for each status >> **and i want to retrieve the value for each status from the lookup list, something as follow**:-

[image]

**So is this possible to implement using sharepoint list workflow 2013?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have the Red Text listed above, you can insert an Action called SET WORKFLOW VARIABLE *(string variable)* or SET FIELD IN CURRENT ITEM and then use settings similar to this below.

NOTE: Where my screenshot says Association: History List -> Yours will say Lookup List

Pay attention to the annotation bubbles in my screenshot below. Point the top section to your Lookup list and your next field called FIELD FROM SOURCE: will be equal to the **Val** column.

On the bottom use the settings that I have listed. You are matching your STATUS value from List 1 to the Title column on the Lookup List.

You may need to mess with the **"Return Field"** try **STRING** OR **Lookup Value (As Text)**.

This should do exactly what you need.

[image]